# A property of symmetric bilinear forms that I think should be true for all bilinear forms.

Tags: linear-algebra

The following is a statement from Artin's Algebra. It is from the section on bilinear forms:

> Let $A $ be the matrix of a symmetric (bilinear) form with respect to a basis. Then the null space of the (bilinear) form is the set of vectors $v $ such that the coordinate vector $X $ of $v $ is a solution of the homogeneous equation $AX=0$

I was wondering why does A have to be symmetric for it? I think this property is true for all bilinear forms, symmetric or not! I think I even have a proof.

My proof:
If $v $ is a null vector of a form$A $, then for every vector $w\in V $, we have $w^T A v=0$. Let $w=(1, 0, 0, \dots, 0) $. In that case we have the first row of $Av $ equal to $0$. Similarly, if $w=(0, 1, 0, 0, \dots, 0) $,  then the second row of $Av  $ is equal to $0$. Proceeding in a similar manner, we see that all rows of $Av $ are equal to $0$,  implying that $Av=0$.

Comment: why do you don't include it?

Comment: @janmarqz- I have added it. Please check it

Answer (score 0):

Take

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

One has

$$A\cdot \begin{pmatrix} y_1\\y_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} y_2\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

And the bilinear form $B_A(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=(\mathbf{x},A\cdot\mathbf{y})=x_1y_2$

Now take $\mathbf{v}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ we have $A\mathbf{v}\neq 0$ and $\forall \mathbf{y}\, B_A(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{y})=0$